# Will not show installation menu!

Tags: boot, hardware

I am trying to load Ubuntu 14.02.2 on my desktop computer. I have repartitioned my solid state drive with a Windows dis, placed the Ubuntu disk in the trey, and selected to boot from the BD-ROM. I get a purple screen for about two seconds and then a black screen with an underscore in the left hand corner for an indefinite amount of time. This never gets to the insulation menu. I have a customized computer { MB: ASRock z77 EUFI BIOS, RM: 16 GB G-Skill, VC: MSI GTX 760, SSD: 256 GB,  CPU: i7-3770K, Monitor: Vizio 55" 4K }. Any advice on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-download the .iso file from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-kylin), or wherever you downloaded it from. Then try to burn that disc image to the disc and try again. May I ask why you are using 14.02.2 instead of 14.04, 14.10, or 15.04?

Comment: Limited bandwidth. I already had 14.02.2 so that's what I was going to use. I will try downloading a newer version and trying it though. I was just wandering if it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

You got a nice system! I built a d-top with the exact same specs except I have an Acer monitor! You need to go into the bios, its like almost the last option (or tab you can select) under boot (with in the bios), select the option to boot 'legacy mode', change the boot order to cd-rom over hard drive; and see if that works.

The mobo is Windows 8.1 ready. So I think thats what I did. Im currently not using that dtop, so I can't verify that; but I think thats right. Its back home.

The re-partitioning can be done during installation by Ubuntu's installation manager. I would back up my data before you try that again.